# Why prevProps always the same to current props in componentDidUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have parent component with the local state like this:

```
this.state = {
  person: null
}
```

And when component renders the person becomes an object with different properties:

```
person = {
  id: 0,
  age: 20,
  name: 'John'
}
```

I passed **this.state.person** to child component, and I want to render it when **person** has another id.

```
if (!prevProps.person) {
            if (this.props.person) {
                this.fetchData(this.props);
                return;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
        if (
            this.props.person &&
            this.props.person.id !==
            prevProps.person.id
        ) {
            this.fetchData(this.props);
 }
```

It doesn't work, because prevProps always is equalt to this.props. How I can fix this?

Comment: @Viet I wrote - I passed this.state.person to child component, so in child component it's props

Comment: You should show more code detail to make sure you update `person`. All codes currently is fine

Comment: @Viet added all code from componentDidUpdate

Comment: I mean how do you pass `this.state.person` and how to you update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you change your state and person object in it.
See the example here, it works correctly.

The first state doesn't have any id, so you get an error. In case if you have some person id and then change the state to new data it's should be new object with a new reference

```
class Person extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   if (prevProps.person !== null && (prevProps.person.id !== this.props.person.id)) {
      console.log('it works');
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    const { person } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        {person && person.name}
      </>
    );
  }
}

class A extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      person: null
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        person: {
          id: 0,
          age: 20,
          name: 'John'
        }
      })
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  render() {
    const { person } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Person person={person} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <A />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition like this `if (prevProps.person !== this.person)`

```
            if (this.props.person) {
                this.fetchData(this.props);
                return;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
        if (
            this.props.person &&
            this.props.person.id !==
            prevProps.person.id
        ) {
            this.fetchData(this.props);
 }
```